# How to get disp_apache2.4.dll for Apache 2.4 version for AEM

Tags: dll

Recently I have installed Apache Http server 2.4 but I need disp_apache2.4.dll. I have gone through number of forums but no luck. Please suggest me some links or forums to get that dll file.

Note : I am using Adobe CQ (AEM)

Comment: Can you accept the answer by @dtr-java to close this question?

Answer (score 2):

Only "Dispatcher for Apache HTTP Server 2.2" is available for IIS on Windows. Dispatcher for Apache HTTP Server 2.4 is not supported and therefore the version you are looking for is not available on this platform.